# MySQL ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s) on returning entries before update

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I need to SELECT all the unsent emails in tbl_emails table, while also updating their status to 'sent'. I select them into @temp first. Then update statuses. Finally, I select @temp.

```
 CREATE DEFINER = root@localhost PROCEDURE get_unsent_emails ()
         SET @temp = (SELECT * FROM tbl_emails WHERE email_sent = 0);
         UPDATE tbl_emails
         SET email_sent = 1
         WHERE email_sent = 0;
         SELECT @temp;
```

I get the following error:

> MySQL ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)

~

Comment: @temp variable should have contain only one column in  query

Answer (score 2):

Why not using a TEMPORARY TABLE in the stored procedure.

```
 CREATE DEFINER = root@localhost PROCEDURE get_unsent_emails ()
         CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp AS (SELECT * FROM tbl_emails WHERE email_sent = 0);
         UPDATE tbl_emails
         SET email_sent = 1
         WHERE email_sent = 0;
         SELECT * FROM temp;
         DROP TEMPORARY TABLE temp;
```

**Edit prevent race condition** 
Because off spencer7593's comment.

I assume there is a id column in the table tbl_emails what is the PRIMARY KEY.

```
 CREATE DEFINER = root@localhost PROCEDURE get_unsent_emails ()
         CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp AS (SELECT * FROM tbl_emails WHERE email_sent = 0);
         UPDATE tbl_emails
         SET email_sent = 1
         WHERE email_sent = 0 AND id IN(SELECT id FROM temp);
         SELECT * FROM temp;
         DROP TEMPORARY TABLE temp;
```

Comment: This pattern is subject to a race condition. Consider what happens when another session inserts a row with `email_sent=0` into `tbl_emails` concurrently with this procedure, where the new row isn't seen by the SELECT but is seen by the UPDATE. A pattern that isn't subject to that would be to only update rows in `tbl_emails` that were inserted into temp. (Using a JOIN operation with the primary key or a unique key from `tbl_emails`.)

Comment: @spencer7593 i really didn't think about a race condition but you are right. That would can cause a race condition.. But you don't have to use a JOIN a `AND id IN (SELECT id FROM temp)` would do just fine.

Comment: +10. For the second form (avoiding the race condition) we could omit `email_sent = 0 AND`.  I'd avoid adding a SELECT and just do an inner join **`UPDATE table_emails t JOIN temp s ON s.pk = t.pk SET t.email_sent = 1`**